# Cocos3d Changing face color

Tags: cocos3d

I am trying to change the color of the face on a CC3MeshNode. I am retrieving the selected face data with the below code.

```
CC3MeshNode*node = (CC3MeshNode*)aNode;
CC3MeshIntersection myMeshIntersection[kMeshHitCountMax];
CC3Ray touchRay = [self.activeCamera unprojectPoint:touchPoint];
CC3Ray localRay = [aNode.globalTransformMatrixInverted transformRay:touchRay];

[node findFirst:kMeshHitCountMax intersections:myMeshIntersection ofLocalRay:localRay acceptBackFaces:NO acceptBehindRay:NO];

CC3FaceIndices indices = [node faceIndicesAt:myMeshIntersection[0].faceIndex];
```

Ive tried to change the VertexColor but it doesn't change anything.

```
ccColor4F color = ccc4f(255, 0, 0, 255);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    [node setVertexColor4F:color at:indices.vertices[i]];
}
```

Nothing happens.

Actually, I changed the vertex color on a object in Maya and I didn't get what I was looking for. I'm actually not sure if changing the VertexColor would be what I should be doing. I want to achieve something like this:

[image]

I'm new to the whole 3d thing, can someone shine a light on a solution?

-Thanks for your time. :)

**EDIT**

I got the above code working, I was just forgetting to update the Buffers

```
[node updateGLBuffers];
```

but it wasn't what I was going after.

Can someone point me in the general direction of what to look up so that I highlight the selected face?

Comment: You haven't indicated what is going wrong. What result did you actually see?

Comment: Well it didn't color only one face, like the image above, it colored along some of the edges connected to those vertices, so the face was colored but so were some parts outside of the face. I'm trying to get an effect like the image above. I'd post an image of the result that I got but I'm not at my computer right now

Comment: Make sure you create (and export) vertices for each face in your model editor, so that at each corner, you actually have three collocated vertices, one per face. If you just have a single vertex at each corner, it is shared by all the faces that extend from that corner, and when you color it, you end up smearing the color across all those faces.

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I was trying to fix.